# Token Sale Smart Contract

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ether, contract-invocation, contract-debugging

I am new to Ethereium Block Chain and have been trying some code written in solidity as follows.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "./MyERC20Token.sol";
import "./ERC20Burnable.sol";


contract MyERC20TokenSale {
address payable admin;
MyERC20Token public tokenContract;
uint256 public tokenPrice;
uint256 public tokensSold;

event Sell(address _buyer, uint256 _amount);

constructor(MyERC20Token _tokenContract, uint256 _tokenPrice) public {
    admin = msg.sender;
    tokenContract = _tokenContract;
    tokenPrice = _tokenPrice;
}

function multiply(uint x, uint y) internal pure returns (uint z) {
    require(y == 0 || (z = x * y) / y == x);
}

function buyTokens(uint256 _numberOfTokens) public payable {
    require(msg.value == multiply(_numberOfTokens, tokenPrice));
    require(tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this)) >= _numberOfTokens);
    require(tokenContract.transfer(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens));

    tokensSold += _numberOfTokens;

    emit Sell(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens);
}

function endSale() public {
    require(msg.sender == admin);
    require(tokenContract.transfer(admin, tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this))));

    admin.transfer(address(this).balance);
}
 }
```

I wish to return all the raised tokens to the admin and burn the unused tokens. But when I am doing endSale(), I am getting Error : invalid opcode.

It will be a really helping if someone can go through this code.

Answer (score 0):

> require(msg.sender == admin);

You need to send the transaction from the same account that deployed the contract. `admin` was set at deployment time with `admin = msg.sender;` in the constructor.

> require(tokenContract.transfer(admin, tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this))));

Transfers the token balance of the sale contract to the admin. Should be okay.

> admin.transfer(address(this).balance);

Transfer the ether balance to admin. Should be okay.

Best guess is you are not meeting the first requirement.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's not helping. I tried. retracing the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved by changing `pragma solidity ^0.5.0` to `pragma solidity ^0.5.1`. It is working now. Thanks for the help.